# How to disable select option based on other select option selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I couldn't figure out the ways to write the code.

I have 2 select tags: they have same options [1,2,3,4,5].

- In select tag ONE, if I choose option 1; select tag TWO does not happen anything;
- In select tag ONE, if I choose option 2; select tag TWO will disable option 1;
- In select tag ONE, if I choose option 3; select tag TWO will disable option 1 and 2;
- In select tag ONE, if I choose option 4; select tag TWO will disable option 1,2 and 3;
- In select tag ONE, if I choose option 5; select tag TWO will disable option 1,2, 3, and 4;
- While user select option 4 in select tag ONE, select tag TWO will re-enable option 3; disable option 1 and 2;
- While user select option 3 in select tag ONE, select tag TWO will re-enable option 2; disable option 1;
- While user select option 2 in select tag ONE, select tag TWO will re-enable option 1; re-enable All option;
- While user select option 1 in select tag ONE, select tag TWO will re-enable All option;

Does anybody know this kind of code, can you show me here, much appreciated.

Comment: what you are done so far?

Comment: Just for selection, a time selection. I have tried to do it in a loop, but it can't work :(

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxetpuom/4/)

```js
$("#1").change(function(){ 
 var selectedOption = $(this).val();

 // Reset
 $("#2").children('option').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', false);
 });

 for (var i = 0; i < selectedOption; i++) {
  $("#2-" + i).attr('disabled','disabled');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="1">
 <option value="1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="3">Option 3</option>
 <option value="4">Option 4</option>
 <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>

<select id="2">
 <option value="1" id="2-1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="2" id="2-2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="3" id="2-3">Option 3</option>
 <option value="4" id="2-4">Option 4</option>
 <option value="5" id="2-5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

EDIT: Updated solution with reset of disabled Attributes

Comment: Ya, it might work! But when I select option 1 in tag ONE again, supposedly select tag TWO will re-enable option 1. But it does not.

Comment: Please check the update above, I also updated the fiddle

Comment: Thanks mate! It's what I need!!! Thank you so much! Please vote me for this question!